# Passing parameters to python script from bash file

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04

I have a python application which starts a websocket on the port which is specified as a parameter to the python application. 
I have done the passing of argument successfully through the batch(.bat) file in windows. 
In windows I am passing the parameter as follows:
python server.py -p 8000

Now I need to achieve the same in ubuntu 12.04 through the bash file. I am starting the python application as a service from bash file.
Code of bash file:

```
PYPATH="/usr/bin/python"
DEAMON="./server.py"

start-stop-daemon --start --background --name $DEAMONNAME --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile  --user $USER --group $USER --chuid $USER -d $WORKINGDIR --exec $PYPATH $DEAMON
```

This works fine when I run as it is, but it takes default port.
I pass parameter as follows :

```
DEAMON="./server.py -p 8004"
```

This gives me following error:

```
start-stop-daemon: invalid option -- 'y'
Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
...fail!
```

Please can any one help me in passing the parameter to the python application from bash file to achieve the same effect as in windows ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html but this question belongs rather to superuser...

Answer (score 1):

Move any arguments not meant directly for `start-stop-daemon` to the very end of the command after `--` so that they are passed through:

```
PYPATH="/usr/bin/python"
DEAMON="./server.py -p 8004"

start-stop-daemon --start --background --name $DEAMONNAME --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $USER --group $USER --chuid $USER -d $WORKINGDIR --exec $PYPATH -- $DEAMON
```